# Are there any open source database server health monitoring softwares?

Tags: database, charts, open-source, health-monitoring

Hi I have been given a task to design tool to monitor database server health like cpu usage, memory usage etc. Now there is one such tool like MySQL Spotlight. I want to know is there any open source software available with same functionalities? I want software which has nice visualization with charts. Please guide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please refer existing answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574401/mysql-monitor-queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) for this. Also look at [Nagios](http://www.nagios.com).

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://code.openark.org/forge/mycheckpoint.  It is an open sourced monitoring tool, primarily for db monitoring, even including custom queries and custom alerts!  Graphs come pre-packaged and pre-generated.  It's written in python, so mods can added to the code easily.  I've used it a bit, and it seems to work pretty well.  The only caveat I see is the extensive schema that comes pre-packaged which, ostensibly, can't be customized.  One thing I will note for the email alerts, if you're getting login or credential alerts, go to line 4338 of the code and just add what you need to the smtplib.SMTP instance.