# Get MySQL server load for a given time frame

Tags: mysql, concurrency, blocking

How can I get all the queries executed for a given time frame in a MySQL server?

I need this to monitor failures on a web service, which I suspect are caused by multiple operations blocking each other.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable [General Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html) on a MySQL server to get all queries executed on a MySQL server.
[Slow log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html) can be helpful in finding out problematic queries executed on MySQL server.

Refer existing answer mentioned here:
[MySQL : Monitor Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574401/mysql-monitor-queries)